What is the most performant way to do arithmetic on a few generic numbers contained within a generic struct in C# in .NET 8+?
What is the most performant way to do arithmetic on a few generic numbers wrapped in an unmanaged, generic, and mutable struct in C# in .NET 8+ ? Unsafe code CAN be used.
What is the best performing way to extract primitive numeric types from a containing struct using generics?
The few primitive numeric types are wrapped inside of an unmanaged, generic, and mutable struct, which is available only via generic context and assumed to be the size of a multiple of TNum's size:
static unsafe void Add<TNum, TStruct>(TStruct s, TNum n) where TNum : unmanaged, INumber<TNum> where TStruct : unmanaged {

}

So the question would be assuming TStruct in the example above contains say exactly 3 TNums which are for example shorts (so the struct's size is 6 bytes). How should the above routine be implemented in the most performant way (we want to add a certain number to each of those 3 shorts in a struct)?
What is the most performant way to "extract" individual TNums from such generic structs:
static unsafe void Add<TNum, TStruct>(TStruct s, TNum n) where TNum : unmanaged, INumber<TNum> where TStruct : unmanaged {
  ref var v0 = ref Unsafe.AsRef<TNum>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref s));
  ref var v1 = ref Unsafe.AsRef<TNum>(Unsafe.Add<TNum>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref s), 1));
  ...
  v0 = ...
  v1 = ...
}

OR
static unsafe void Add<TNum, TStruct>(TStruct s, TNum n) where TNum : unmanaged, INumber<TNum> where TStruct : unmanaged {
  var v = (TNum*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref s);
  v[0] = ...
  v[1] = ...
}

OR
Something else?
What is the best performing, likely SIMD-assisted way to perform same arithmetic operation on a few (2-6) generic numbers?
And then, once the TNums have been "extracted", what is the mst efficient way to perform the same arithmetic operation on them in a generic context (we do not know ahead of time what specific primitive type TNums will end up being)?
So, given generic math support in .NET 8+, I am looking for a most efficient way to perform basic arithmetic on generic primitive TNums (like byte, short, int, float and a few others) when there are a few of them (i.e. more than 1, but less than say 6 - similar to struct example above).
One could use System.Numerics.Vector and System.Numerics.Vector<T>, however the problem there is that the size of the vector must match the total size of the primitives you are working with, which is not possible in the generic scenario.
So is there some general approach that will work on modern processors regardless of the underlying primitive type to say for example SIMD-add 3 primitive numbers, or to add a constant to all 3 of them? Unsafe code can be used.
UPDATE:
Just to clarify:

This question is not about a specific problem, rather it applies really to any unamanged (contains no pointers to managed objects) and mutable struct that for the purposes of this question is really just a blob of in-memory bits where it is known in advance that it is a multiple of TNum in size and its layout is sequential.
The code is going to be performed many millions of times, so performance is an issue, and if it was ok with just doing it one field at a time, I would not have posted the question.


Unless you know for certain that performance will be an issue it isn't worth worrying about micro optimisations for a handful of arithmetic operations. If the vectors were a few thousand or longer then it might be worthwhile. Always use a profiler to find the hotspots - premature optimisation just makes code harder to maintain and work on.

I'd suggest taking a look at Which is faster? by Eric Lippert.  There's no substitute for benchmarking it yourself.  That being said, can you share more details about TStruct?  Can you modify it to add methods?  Is there only one TStruct or do you have several similar ones?  If more than one do they share a common interface?  Can you share some examples?

@MartinBrown Thanks for noting this. But the question is specifically about performance. I would not have asked it if I was ok with simply doing it one field at a time.

@dbc Thank you for your suggestion. This is about unmanaged structs in general (i.e. those that contain no managed objects), but think of a primitive ones like a Rectangle for example. Yest structs are modifiable. Interfaces play no role in this problem, the whole point is that the structs are essentially unmanaged blobs of bits in memory, i.e. we are not talking about accessing some properties on them for this example.

@FitDev - If you can modify the structs I suspect that the fastest performing solution would be to implement some interface that includes Add<TNum, TStruct> on each one.  The compiler and JITter could then optimize that (by unfolding loops or using SIMD or whatever else works best for that struct's specific layout).  (Also, are your structs mutable?)

Try writing sample SSE2 code to do say 4 32 bit integers using SIMD then benchmark  and see if the performance gains are really worth the effort. Edge effects for 3,5,6 will make the code tricky and likely negate any performance gain you might otherwise have had for the one special case.

@dbc Yeah, sorry forgot to mention - they are mutable. But the interface approach is no go for me, because this is supposed to work in general - in different structs that may have nothing in common with each other interface-wise, i.e. a rectangle and a color for example.

If they're mutable the you have to pass them as ref TStruct s, otherwise the mutation won't be propagated outside the method.

@MartinBrown But how do I do that in the first place? That's what I am asking actually. I am not too versed with modern DotNet-specific SIMD intrinsics or other APIs that should work on arbitrary generic number types.

@dbc I know that. But I am asking about "extracting" TNums from TStruct as efficiently as possible (really should be free like reinterpret cast or something). And then  performing the same arithmetic operation on these generic TNums using SIMD using some sort of existing DotNet API / intrinsic suitable for the purpose - I am not too familar with these hence my question.

I suspect (but am not sure) that your requirement to maximize performance via micro-optimization of code that is completely generic and duck-typed is contradictory.  Happy to be proved wrong though.  One final question: you wrote that the code will be performed many millions of times, are you calling Add on an array with many items, or looping many times and calling Add on a single item?

SIMD is hard to use for small sizes that aren't a power of 2, especially without AVX-512 or SVE for masking to e.g. only load/store the first 3 elements (6 bytes) of a 128-bit vector, even if we're just considering assembly without yet worrying about how to convince a compiler to emit it.  The details matter a lot, like where do the values you're adding come from?  Can you vpbroadcastw xmm0, eax to replicate the same value?  Or do you need to get 3 different values from non-contiguous locations into elements of an XMM vector?

If you know what comes next in memory after your object, do you know no other threads will be writing it either?  If so, you can safely load / add with [2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] / store a 128-bit vector.  That involves a non-atomic load/store of bytes outside this object so isn't thread-safe.  (You'd need AVX-512 masking to make it safe, or e.g. do 4 bytes with vmovd load / vpaddw (upper elements being don't-care garbage) / vmovd store and do the last element with scalar integer. Barely worth it when you're just SIMDing 2 elements, better with e.g. 10 bytes of shorts doing 8 with SIMD.)

Besides thread safety, though, a wider load could lead to store-forwarding stalls when a load isn't fully contained within a recent store, or fully non-overlapping with any recent stores.  So it depends what you're doing with surrounding bytes.  As @dbc says, if you actually have arrays of these small structs that you want to loop over, then SIMD can shine at least in theory.  e.g. if you want to add {1,2,3} to structs of u16, you can unroll to LCM(3,8) = 24 elements = 48 bytes = 3x 16-byte SIMD vectors (or one 32 one 16) so one loop iteration doing 3 vpaddw can add to 8 structs.

If you have separate scattered structs, but you're doing it in a loop that runs millions of iterations, then the overhead of setting up AVX-512 mask registers and preparing a vector constant can be amortized even if you only have 3-element structs.  But if you're doing it as a one-off between other computation that can't inline into a loop, I'm less optimistic there's anything to gain for 3-element structs.  4-element sure, that'll be some power-of-2 size so one SIMD load/store with no masking.

@PeterCordes Thank you very much for providing such details. Very useful! In my case there will be definitely struct variants with 4 elements in them, which is why I though about SIMD in the first place. I guess I can split my code to deal with 2- and 3- element structs normally, and to deal with 4 element structs in a SIMD-fashion. Though I still am not sure how to do it generically in DotNet even if I do know the struct has 4 elements.

@PeterCordes And yes, in most of my cases these will be done in a loop, hence repeated millions of times on different struct instances, each laid out sequentially as in an array.

each laid out sequentially as in an array. -- If you're operating on an array then calling Add() on each individual array item probably isn't the right way to go.  Instead reinterpret the array as an array of TNum types, then operate on that array e.g. as shown in this SIMD doc example.  Also be sure to pass the array items by ref to avoid copying.

@dbc It's the second: "looping many times and calling Add on a single item". Hence the need to optimize as much as possible. The array approach just would not work here for architectural reasons (even though the actual structs are basically in an array most of the time).

Are you adding a different value to each array item then?  Really a more concrete [mcve] would help us help you here.

"looping many times and calling Add on a single item" - but a different one each time, otherwise you could just accumulate in a wide-enough SIMD vector and add once? And not accessed in sequential order?  Like dbc said, we need a clearer [mcve], preferably as an [edit] to the question not just tidbits of like 1 detail out of many that we asked for scattered in comments.  (Another important one you didn't mention is where the values to be added come from, how easy it is to get them into SIMD vectors or compute them there in the first place.)

The "obvious" path is to implement multiple "non-generic" solutions; and then consolidate them into a "generic" solution ... if it is feasible. As it stands, there has not been enough to prove the feasibility of generics for "all" cases thought to be under consideration. Ultimately "a" generic solution can be arrived at; but may wind up being hard to maintain.

Example: MODBUS protocol. A "type" defines the layout of a function; which is a repeating set of registers (arrays of bytes, half words and words). An abstract base class handles the "primitive" operations on the arrays; while the "function" subclass directs the base class operations. That can be made generic; but for no benefit (IMO). Some 16-20 "functions". Once you have an array of "types" it's easy to make that generic; "wrapping" the entire "function" (or struct), and maintaining clarity, is another matter.

I was able to get some somewhat interesting results, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/TGwr4b.  It might be worth reopening the question, especially if you could add more of a [mcve].  Summary: 1) Be sure to always use ref.  2) For a single item, a hardcoded method is best, reinterpreting the ref as a Span<TNum> and iterating through the span is second best.  3) unsafe pointers don't seem to beat spans.  4) When adding a constant value to a large array of items, reinterpreting to Vector<TNum> wins by a factor of 2 even over a hardcoded method.

Some updated results here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/foZnge.  With a bit more detail in your question it could reopened and some answers added in place of this long comment thread.

You have a huge array of a generic, mutable struct TContainer that consists entirely of a few unmanaged primitive numbers of the same type TNumber, and you would like to find the most performant way to do generic math on the values in the structs, for instance adding a constant value to all the fields.
First, some terminology.  An array of primitive numbers, or a struct containing primitive numbers of uniform type, or an array of such structs, can all be treated in a uniform manner by using spans.  For instance, a value tuple of doubles can be mutated by reinterpreting a reference to it as a span of doubles using MemoryMarshal.Cast():
var tuple = (1.0, 1.0);
var span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<(double, double), double>(new Span<(double, double)>(ref tuple));
foreach (ref var d in span)
    d += 1.0;
Console.WriteLine(tuple); // Prints (2, 2)

Since the same foreach loop could be used to mutate a span referring to an array of doubles, spans provide a convenient (and performant) tool to address your problem.
When doing generic math on spans of numbers, you could try using Vector<T> to speed your numeric operations using SIMD instructions:[1]

The Vector<T> gives the ability to use longer [SIMD] vectors. The count of a Vector<T> instance is fixed, but its value Vector<T>.Count depends on the CPU of the machine running the code.

On my computer the fixed size of Vector<T> is 32 bytes, but apparently 16 bytes is also common, see here for details.  If the number of fields in your Container ls greater than or equal to Vector<TNumber>.Count you could try to mutate it using SIMD instructions.  Similarly if you need to mutate all the structs in your huge array (or some large slice of the same) by adding some fixed value to all of them you could also use Vector<TNumber>.
With that in mind, I created large arrays of a couple of test structs, both at least 32 bytes in size:
public struct Box3D<TNumber> where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber>
{
    public Point3D<TNumber> Min, Max;
}
public struct Point3D<TNumber> where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber>
{
    public TNumber X, Y, Z;
}

And
ValueTuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float> // 8 floats

And created several candidate methods to transform spans of them generically:

Passing the TContainer by reference, span, or value.
Either using Vector<T> if possible, not using it at all, or using some pre-initialized vector passed by reference or value.
Using unsafe pointer arithmetic or not.
Or using some hardcoded transformation method for comparison.

The methods are:
public static partial class NumericExtensions
{
    //-- Methods to add some number to some container reference(s) with automatic vectorization when possible

    public static Span<TContainer> AddToContainerSpan<TContainer, TNumber>(Span<TContainer> span, TNumber n) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
    {
        Debug.Assert((Unsafe.SizeOf<TContainer>() >= Unsafe.SizeOf<TNumber>())); // We are assuming that TContainer contains one or more TNumber fields, so it makes no sense if TContainer is smaller than TNumber

        AddToSpan<TNumber>(MemoryMarshal.Cast<TContainer, TNumber>(span), n);
        return span;
    }

    public static ref TContainer AddToContainerRef<TContainer, TNumber>(ref TContainer s, TNumber n) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
    {
        Debug.Assert(Unsafe.SizeOf<TContainer>() >= Unsafe.SizeOf<TNumber>());

        AddToSpan(MemoryMarshal.Cast<TContainer, TNumber>(new Span<TContainer>(ref s)), n);
        return ref s;
    }

    public static Span<TNumber> AddToSpan<TNumber>(Span<TNumber> span, TNumber n) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber>
    {
        Debug.Assert(Vector<TNumber>.IsSupported); // Not checked in release builds for performance

        if (Vector<TNumber>.Count is var vectorLength
            // Here you could check for length being >= some multiple of vectorLength if you determine a point where the benefits of vectorization outweigh the setup costs
            && span.Length >= vectorLength) 
        {   
            int remaining = span.Length % vectorLength;
            var offset =  new Vector<TNumber>(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < span.Length - remaining; i += vectorLength)
            {
                var slice = span.Slice(i, vectorLength);
                var v1 = new Vector<TNumber>(slice);
                (v1 + offset).CopyTo(slice);
            }
            for (int i = span.Length - remaining; i < span.Length; i++)
                span[i] += n;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i  = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
                span[i] += n;
        }
        return span;
    }

    //-- Methods to add some number to some container reference(s) with no vectorization

    public static Span<TContainer> AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization<TContainer, TNumber>(Span<TContainer> span, TNumber n) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
    {
        Debug.Assert(Unsafe.SizeOf<TContainer>() >= Unsafe.SizeOf<TNumber>());

        var numberSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<TContainer, TNumber>(span);
        for (int i  = 0; i < numberSpan.Length; i++) // Inlined for efficiency.
            numberSpan[i] += n;
        return span;
    }

    public static ref TContainer AddToContainerRefNoVectorization<TContainer, TNumber>(ref TContainer s, TNumber n) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
    {
        Debug.Assert(Unsafe.SizeOf<TContainer>() >= Unsafe.SizeOf<TNumber>());

        var numberSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<TContainer, TNumber>(new Span<TContainer>(ref s));
        for (int i  = 0; i < numberSpan.Length; i++) // Inlined for efficiency.
            numberSpan[i] += n;
        return ref s;
    }
    
    public static Span<TNumber> AddToSpanNoVectorization<TNumber>(Span<TNumber> span, TNumber n) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber>
    {
        for (int i  = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
            span[i] += n;
        return span;
    }
    
    //-- Methods to add some predefined Vector<TNumber> to some container reference(s)

    public static Span<TContainer> AddVectorRefToContainerSpan<TContainer, TNumber>(Span<TContainer> span, ref readonly Vector<TNumber> offsetVector) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
    {
        Debug.Assert(Unsafe.SizeOf<TContainer>() >= Unsafe.SizeOf<TNumber>());

        AddVectorRefToSpan<TNumber>(MemoryMarshal.Cast<TContainer, TNumber>(span), in offsetVector);
        return span;
    }

    public static Span<TNumber> AddVectorRefToSpan<TNumber>(Span<TNumber> span, ref readonly Vector<TNumber> offsetVector) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber>
    {
        // Modeled on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/simd#vectort
        // Vector<TNumber>.IsSupported should be checked by caller
        Debug.Assert(Vector<TNumber>.IsSupported); // Not checked in release builds for performance

        var vectorLength = Vector<TNumber>.Count;
        var length = span.Length;
        int remaining = length % vectorLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - remaining; i += vectorLength)
        {
            var slice = span.Slice(i, vectorLength);
            var v1 = new Vector<TNumber>(slice);
            (v1 + offsetVector).CopyTo(slice);
        }
        if (remaining > 0)
        {
            var remainingSpan = span.Slice(length - remaining);
            for (int i = 0; i < remainingSpan.Length; i++)
            {
                remainingSpan[i] += offsetVector[i];
            }
        }
        return span;
    }

    public static Span<TContainer> AddVectorValueToContainerSpan<TContainer, TNumber>(Span<TContainer> span, Vector<TNumber> offsetVector) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
    {
        Debug.Assert(Unsafe.SizeOf<TContainer>() >= Unsafe.SizeOf<TNumber>());

        AddVectorValueToSpan<TNumber>(MemoryMarshal.Cast<TContainer, TNumber>(span), offsetVector);
        return span;
    }

    public static Span<TNumber> AddVectorValueToSpan<TNumber>(Span<TNumber> span, Vector<TNumber> offsetVector) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber>
    {
        // Modeled on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/simd#vectort
        // Vector<TNumber>.IsSupported should be checked by caller
        Debug.Assert(Vector<TNumber>.IsSupported); // Not checked in release builds for performance

        var vectorLength = Vector<TNumber>.Count;
        var length = span.Length;
        int remaining = length % vectorLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - remaining; i += vectorLength)
        {
            var slice = span.Slice(i, vectorLength);
            var v1 = new Vector<TNumber>(slice);
            (v1 + offsetVector).CopyTo(slice);
        }
        if (remaining > 0)
        {
            var remainingSpan = span.Slice(length - remaining);
            for (int i = 0; i < remainingSpan.Length; i++)
            {
                remainingSpan[i] += offsetVector[i];
            }
        }
        return span;
    }

#if !NOUNSAFE   
    //-- Method to add some number to some container(s) using unsafe pointer arithmetic

    public static unsafe ref TContainer AddToContainerUnsafe<TContainer, TNumber>(ref TContainer s, TNumber n) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged 
    {
        var span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<TContainer, TNumber>(new Span<TContainer>(ref s));
        fixed (TNumber *pNumber = span)
        {
            for (int i = 0, count = span.Length; i < count ; i++)
            {
                pNumber[i] += n;
            }
        }
        return ref s;
    }
#endif 

    //-- Method to add some number to some container(s) BY COPY with no vectorization

    public static TContainer AddToContainerValueNoVectorization<TContainer, TNumber>(TContainer s, TNumber n) where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
    {
        // Generic struct + math
        var span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<TContainer, TNumber>(new Span<TContainer>(ref s));
        for (int i  = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
            span[i] += n;
        return s;
    }

    //-- Hardcoded method to add a double to a Box3D<double>

    public static ref Box3D<double> AddHardcoded(ref Box3D<double> s, double n)
    {
        // Hardcoded struct, double math
        s.Min.X += n;
        s.Min.Y += n;
        s.Min.Z += n;
        s.Max.X += n;
        s.Max.Y += n;
        s.Max.Z += n;
        
        return ref s;
    }
}

Then, using BenchmarkDotNet I created benchmarks for all the above using arrays of Box3D<double> and value tuples of 8 floats, using arrays of length 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10 and 1000 and ran them in .NET 8:
public partial class Box3DTestClass
{
    //https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/features/setup-and-cleanup.html
    [Params(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 1000)]
    public int ArrayCount;

    private Box3D<double> [] array = [];
    Vector<double> offsetVector;
    double offset;
    
    [GlobalSetup]
    public void SetupArrays()
    {
        array = new Box3D<double>[ArrayCount];
        Array.Fill(array, new () { Min = new() { X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 }, Max = new() { X = 2, Y = 2, Z = 2 }});
        offset = 2.0;
        offsetVector = new Vector<double>(offset);
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the entire array at oncce
        NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpan(array.AsSpan(), offset);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerSpans()
    {
        var span = array.AsSpan();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpan(span.Slice(i, 1), offset);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the array item by item by reference
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerRef(ref array[i], offset);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the entire array at oncce but without vectorization
        NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization(array.AsSpan(), offset);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerSpansNoVectorization()
    {
        var span = array.AsSpan();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization(span.Slice(i, 1), offset);
        }
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the array item by item by reference
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerRefNoVectorization(ref array[i], offset);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddVectorRefToContainerSpan()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the entire array at oncce
        NumericExtensions.AddVectorRefToContainerSpan(array.AsSpan(), ref offsetVector);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddVectorValueToContainerSpan()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the entire array at oncce
        NumericExtensions.AddVectorValueToContainerSpan(array.AsSpan(), offsetVector);
    }

#if !NOUNSAFE   
    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToContainerUnsafe()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the array item by item by reference using unsafe code
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerUnsafe(ref array[i], offset);
        }
    }
#endif  

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToContainerValueNoVectorization()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the array item by item by copy
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = NumericExtensions.AddToContainerValueNoVectorization(array[i], offset);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddHardcoded()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the array item by item using a builtin hardcoded method 
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddHardcoded(ref array[i], offset);
        }
    }
}

public partial class TupleTestClass
{
    //https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/features/setup-and-cleanup.html
    [Params(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 1000)]
    public int ArrayCount;

    // I chose a tuple of 8 floats because it's the same size as Vector<float>
    private (float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float) [] array = [];
    Vector<float> offsetVector;
    float offset;
    
    [GlobalSetup]
    public void SetupArrays()
    {
        array = new (float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)[ArrayCount];
        Array.Fill(array, (1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f, 8f));
        offset = 2.0f;
        offsetVector = new Vector<float>(offset);
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the entire array at oncce
        NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpan(array.AsSpan(), offset);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerSpans()
    {
        var span = array.AsSpan();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpan(span.Slice(i, 1), offset);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the array item by item by reference
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerRef(ref array[i], offset);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the entire array at oncce but without vectorization
        NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization(array.AsSpan(), offset);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerSpansNoVectorization()
    {
        var span = array.AsSpan();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization(span.Slice(i, 1), offset);
        }
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the array item by item by reference
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerRefNoVectorization(ref array[i], offset);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddVectorRefToContainerSpan()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the entire array at oncce
        NumericExtensions.AddVectorRefToContainerSpan(array.AsSpan(), ref offsetVector);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Benchmark_AddVectorValueToContainerSpan()
    {
        // Benchmark adding a value to the entire array at oncce
        NumericExtensions.AddVectorValueToContainerSpan(array.AsSpan(), offsetVector);
    }
}

I can summarize the results as follows:

Always access and pass your structs by reference rather than by value.  Access them using reference variables and pass them using reference parameters, e.g:
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    ref item = ref array[i];
    // Call some method to modify `item` passing it by reference:
    Modify(ref item);
}

Passing by value could slow your algorithm down by 3-6 times.  You won't be able to use LINQ when using spans and reference variables, but you probably don't want to anyway in truly performance-critical code.

The fastest way to mutate a single reference to a TContainer is to use a hardcoded method:
// An array with just one item to mutate:
Box3D<double> [] array = [(new Box3D<double>() { Min = new() { X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 }, Max = new() { X = 2, Y = 2, Z = 2 } })];
double offset = 2.0;

// Add a value to the array item by item using a builtin hardcoded method 
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    NumericExtensions.AddHardcoded(ref array[i], offset);
}

The fastest generic way is to reinterpret the reference as a span of numbers, and mutate that without vectorization:
// Add a value to the array item by item by reference
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    NumericExtensions.AddToContainerRefNoVectorization(ref array[i], offset);
}

Creating an offset vector via new Vector<TNumber>(offset) apparently has some costs that does not pay off for a single addition.

The fastest way to mutate multiple TContainer values in a span by adding a fixed offset (if you can reorganize your algorithm to do this) depends on the number of items.  Once the amount of data to mutate exceeds 2 to 3 the size of  Vector<TNumber>.Count, vectorization becomes faster than transforming the span item by item.  And once it exceeds 3 to 4 the size it's even faster than using the hardcoded method:
// An array of items larger than 4 * Vector<double>.Count:
Box3D<double> [] array = Enumerable.Repeat(new Box3D<double>() { Min = new() { X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 }, Max = new() { X = 2, Y = 2, Z = 2 } }, 4).ToArray();
double offset = 2.0;

// Add a value to the entire array at once using vectorization 
NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpan(array.AsSpan(), offset);

The precise transition points seemed to depend on the size of the structs and specific type of number.  They probably also depend on processor details so you will need to test for yourself.  For large spans addition using vectorization was roughly 3 times faster than item-by-item generic addition, and twice as fast as using the hardcoded method item by item.

Using unsafe pointer arithmetic was never faster than using spans, much less vectorization.  (Perhaps the Jitter can optimize the code better?)

Using a pre-initialized Vector<T> and passing it into the Add() method, either by reference or by value, was slower than constructing it internally.  (This was also a little surprising to me.)

As suggested in comments, you might create some generic worker interface where you use generic methods to transform arbitrary struct types, but substitute in efficient hardcoded methods when present, e.g.:
public interface INumericWorker<TContainer, TNumber> where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
{
    void ModifyItem(ref TContainer item, TNumber value);
    void ModifySpan(Span<TContainer> items, TNumber value);
}

public sealed class GenericAddWorker<TContainer, TNumber> : INumericWorker<TContainer, TNumber> where TNumber : unmanaged, INumber<TNumber> where TContainer : unmanaged
{
    public void ModifyItem(ref TContainer item, TNumber value) => NumericExtensions.AddToContainerRefNoVectorization(ref item, value);
    public void ModifySpan(Span<TContainer> items, TNumber value) =>  NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpan(items, value);
}

public sealed class Box3dDoubleAddAddWorker : INumericWorker<Box3D<double>, double>
{
    public void ModifyItem(ref Box3D<double> item, double value) => NumericExtensions.AddHardcoded(ref item, value);
    public void ModifySpan(Span<Box3D<double>> items, double value)
    {
        if (items.Length < 4)
        {
            foreach (ref var item in items)
                NumericExtensions.AddHardcoded(ref item, value);
        }
        else
        {
            NumericExtensions.AddToContainerSpan(items, value);
        }
    }
}



Selected benchmark results are as follows:
BenchmarkDotNet v0.14.0, Windows 10 (10.0.19045.4780/22H2/2022Update)
Intel Core i7-9750H CPU 2.60GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK 8.0.203
  [Host]     : .NET 8.0.8 (8.0.824.36612), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
  DefaultJob : .NET 8.0.8 (8.0.824.36612), X64 RyuJIT AVX2


| Method                                                 | ArrayCount | Mean         | Error       | StdDev      | Median       |
|------------------------------------------------------- |----------- |-------------:|------------:|------------:|-------------:|
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan                           | 1          |     5.030 ns |   0.1008 ns |   0.0894 ns |     5.066 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs                 | 1          |     4.945 ns |   0.0157 ns |   0.0123 ns |     4.944 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization            | 1          |     5.426 ns |   0.0204 ns |   0.0181 ns |     5.429 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization  | 1          |     2.528 ns |   0.0149 ns |   0.0139 ns |     2.523 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerUnsafe                         | 1          |     3.217 ns |   0.0228 ns |   0.0190 ns |     3.221 ns |
| Benchmark_AddHardcoded                                 | 1          |     2.122 ns |   0.0408 ns |   0.0382 ns |     2.147 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan                           | 2          |     4.881 ns |   0.1224 ns |   0.1310 ns |     4.954 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs                 | 2          |    10.677 ns |   0.0259 ns |   0.0242 ns |    10.680 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization            | 2          |     7.294 ns |   0.0529 ns |   0.0442 ns |     7.277 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization  | 2          |     5.500 ns |   0.0186 ns |   0.0174 ns |     5.495 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerUnsafe                         | 2          |     6.719 ns |   0.0255 ns |   0.0239 ns |     6.721 ns |
| Benchmark_AddHardcoded                                 | 2          |     4.550 ns |   0.0236 ns |   0.0221 ns |     4.542 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan                           | 3          |     6.683 ns |   0.0952 ns |   0.0890 ns |     6.696 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs                 | 3          |    14.438 ns |   0.0295 ns |   0.0261 ns |    14.434 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization            | 3          |    10.221 ns |   0.2228 ns |   0.2084 ns |    10.113 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization  | 3          |     8.758 ns |   0.0395 ns |   0.0370 ns |     8.771 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerUnsafe                         | 3          |    10.260 ns |   0.1129 ns |   0.1056 ns |    10.313 ns |
| Benchmark_AddHardcoded                                 | 3          |     6.490 ns |   0.0424 ns |   0.0396 ns |     6.487 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan                           | 4          |     6.240 ns |   0.0089 ns |   0.0074 ns |     6.237 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs                 | 4          |    19.838 ns |   0.0596 ns |   0.0466 ns |    19.839 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization            | 4          |    13.145 ns |   0.2296 ns |   0.2035 ns |    13.117 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization  | 4          |    11.729 ns |   0.1569 ns |   0.1468 ns |    11.673 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerUnsafe                         | 4          |    13.669 ns |   0.2959 ns |   0.2768 ns |    13.743 ns |
| Benchmark_AddHardcoded                                 | 4          |     8.255 ns |   0.0196 ns |   0.0174 ns |     8.252 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan                           | 5          |     8.353 ns |   0.1941 ns |   0.2235 ns |     8.367 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs                 | 5          |    25.891 ns |   0.5423 ns |   0.7239 ns |    26.297 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization            | 5          |    16.649 ns |   0.1018 ns |   0.0850 ns |    16.656 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization  | 5          |    15.326 ns |   0.1264 ns |   0.1056 ns |    15.366 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerUnsafe                         | 5          |    18.024 ns |   0.0595 ns |   0.0527 ns |    18.040 ns |
| Benchmark_AddHardcoded                                 | 5          |    11.132 ns |   0.0524 ns |   0.0437 ns |    11.144 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan                           | 10         |    13.641 ns |   0.0261 ns |   0.0244 ns |    13.646 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs                 | 10         |    54.563 ns |   0.1820 ns |   0.1613 ns |    54.605 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization            | 10         |    32.991 ns |   0.0676 ns |   0.0632 ns |    33.003 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization  | 10         |    32.270 ns |   0.4208 ns |   0.3731 ns |    32.224 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerUnsafe                         | 10         |    36.502 ns |   0.0796 ns |   0.0706 ns |    36.520 ns |
| Benchmark_AddHardcoded                                 | 10         |    23.832 ns |   0.0247 ns |   0.0206 ns |    23.832 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpan                           | 1000       |   928.463 ns |  18.2194 ns |  24.3224 ns |   911.696 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefs                 | 1000       | 4,923.470 ns |   7.0736 ns |   6.2706 ns | 4,924.709 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerSpanNoVectorization            | 1000       | 2,987.166 ns |  20.5200 ns |  17.1351 ns | 2,989.880 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToSingleItemContainerRefsNoVectorization  | 1000       | 3,134.353 ns |  45.2252 ns |  35.3089 ns | 3,131.778 ns |
| Benchmark_AddToContainerUnsafe                         | 1000       | 3,582.236 ns |   7.7057 ns |   6.8309 ns | 3,581.778 ns |
| Benchmark_AddHardcoded                                 | 1000       | 2,130.239 ns |  40.3144 ns |  37.7101 ns | 2,111.256 ns |

Full results + code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W6IJXh


[1]There are also smaller SIMD types specifically for float values such as Vector2 however these do not meet your requirement of being generic.

